# Accessing a superclass arraylist in a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, subclass, superclass

Hopefully i can describe my problem as intended: I have 2 classes; JavaApplication65(please don't question the name :D) and a subclass of JavaApplication65, Logs. Now I have an ArrayList in JavaApplication65 named temp and i want to copy its values into an Arraylist called allLogsText in Logs. How can I do it?

```
package javaapplication65;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author MertKarakas
 */
public class JavaApplication65 {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
Logs importer = new Logs();
private String nameOfLog;
private String wholeLog;
static ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();

/**
 *
 * @param nameOfLog1
 * @param wholeLog1
 */
public JavaApplication65(String nameOfLog1, String wholeLog1){
    this.nameOfLog = nameOfLog1;
    this.wholeLog = wholeLog1;
}
public JavaApplication65(){}
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    System.out.println("Data Log V1. @author MertKarakas");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("/Users/mertkarakas/Desktop/Logs/LogList.txt"));
    while (s.hasNext()){
        temp.add(s.next());
        }
    s.close();
    new Logs().menuOpt();

}
}


public class Logs {
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<JavaApplication65> allLogs = new ArrayList<JavaApplication65>();
ArrayList<String> allLogsText = new ArrayList<String>(JavaApplication65.temp);
private String name;
public void Logs(){
    this.name = "";
}

public void menuOpt(){
    System.out.println("Menu: Write a log[log], See entered logs[see] --> Read an entered log[#], Delete a log[del], Read a specific log[spf]");
    WriteStringToFile2(allLogsText);
    choices();
    WriteStringToFile2(allLogsText);
}

public void choices(){
    String input1 = console.next();
    if ( input1.equalsIgnoreCase("log") ){
        log();
    }else if ( input1.equalsIgnoreCase("see") ){
        getLogs();
        System.out.println("Enter the index of requested log: ");
        int requestedLog = console.nextInt();
        getALog(requestedLog);
    }else if( input1.equalsIgnoreCase("del") ){

    }else if ( input1.equalsIgnoreCase("spf") ){

    }else{
        System.out.println("Wrong input, returnin to menu.");
        menuOpt();
    }
}
public void log(){
    System.out.println("Enter name of the log: ");
    String logName2 = console.next();
    System.out.println("Enter your log: ");
    String wholeLog2 = console.next();
    WriteStringToFile(logName2, wholeLog2);
    JavaApplication65 tempLog = new JavaApplication65(logName2, wholeLog2);
    allLogs.add(allLogs.size(), tempLog);
    allLogsText.add(allLogsText.size(), logName2);
    getLogs();
    System.out.println("Log successfully added.");

}

public List<String> getLogs(){
    return allLogsText.subList(0, allLogsText.size());
}
public String getALog(int k){
    String temp = allLogsText.get(k);
    return temp;
}

public void WriteStringToFile(String logNamerino, String wholeLogarino){
        try {
        String str = wholeLogarino;
        File newTextFile = new File("/Users/mertkarakas/Desktop/Logs/" + logNamerino + ".txt");

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
        fw.write(str);
        fw.close();

    } catch (IOException iox) {
    }
}
    public void WriteStringToFile2(ArrayList<String> list){  
        try {
            for(int k =0; k < list.size(); k++){
                String str = list.get(k);
                File newTextFile = new      File("/Users/mertkarakas/Desktop/Logs/LogList.txt");
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
                fw.write(str);
                fw.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException iox) {
    }
}
```

}

As you can see at the last line of code(ArrayList allLogsText = new ArrayList(temp)), it gives out an error that "Cannot find symbol" for temp. Help me please... Thanks on advance.**UPDATE** I made a tweak "ArrayList allLogsText = new ArrayList(JavaApplication65.temp);" I made it JavaApplication65.temp and it seems to work. But will it work? My intension is to make a sort of journal and with this line of code ill try to obtain every entry that has been written to the LogList.txt**

Comment: What you are trying to achieve here ?? Why you are wanting to put the temp in main ?? You are wrong at several concepts. Can you please describe what is your aim ? Do not mix static members and instance members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Scope matters.

The `List` you are accessing is local to the `main()` method. You can access that only within the `main()` method.

Move that to top level, which should be an instance member( and provide a getter to return that as well) to access.

Comment: I did that however, now it said main is a static method, so the arraylist should be static as well. Did that as well but still gives the error "Cannot find symbol, symbol: variable temp, location: class Logs"

Comment: @user3141704 Can you please update the post with latest codes ?

Answer (score 0):

Your temp list is **Method Local** and if you want to use attributes in subclass then declare those attributes in **class level** of your Super class. Like this:

```
public class JavaApplication65 {
    ArrayList<String> temp;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    JavaApplication65 java= new JavaApplication65();    
    java.temp = new ArrayList<String>();

    }
}

public class Logs extends JavaApplication65 {
     Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
     ArrayList<JavaApplication65> allLogs = new ArrayList<JavaApplication65>();
     ArrayList<String> allLogsText = new ArrayList<String>(temp);
}
```

Comment: This didn't change anything. It still does give the same error.

Comment: Couldn't find symbol.